# definition of complex differentiable function

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Here is one of the definitions of a complex differentiable function:

> If the function $f$ is defined in a neighbourhood of a point $c\in \mathbb{C}$ we say that $f$ is **(complex) differentiable** at c if
>
> $f(z) = f(c) + L(z-c) + \eta \\$
>   where thw complex number L is independent of z and
>   $\frac{\eta }{\left | z-c \right |} \rightarrow 0$ as $z \rightarrow c$
>
> In this case, we write $L=f'(c)$ and call $f'$ the **(complex) derivative** of f.

My question is, why do we use $\frac{\eta}{\left |z-c \right |}$ instead of just  $\eta$ in our definition?

Comment: You want $z\to c$, right?

Comment: @sharding4 Oops...typo!

Answer (score 1):

If you think about the definition in terms of difference quotients, you'll want $$\frac{f(z)-f(c)}{z-c}\to L\text{ as }z\to c$$

$\dfrac{\eta}{z-c}$ could blow up without that condition.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you elaborate more? I don't quite get it...why would we want to think in terms of difference quotients?

Comment: I thought you might be more familiar with the definition in terms of difference quotients, and if you think about rewriting the definition you gave above in those terms, it should be clearer as to why you need the $\eta/|z-c|\to0$.